# Аналог partial class для разных assemblies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, архитектура

Мне необходимо реализовать несколько сайтов на ASP.NET MVC (C#).

Во всех сайтах есть общие компоненты (пользователи (регистрация, вход, личные сообщения, восстановление пароля и т.д.), группы, админка, новости и т.д.). Соответственно, я хочу сделать одну общую библиотеку для использования во всех проектах.

Проблема заключается в том, что нужно иметь возможность добавлять поля классам библиотеки, при этом и библиотека должна знать о новых полях (для правильной загрузки из бд (используется OrmLite) и кэширования (используется redis)).

К тому же хотелось бы избежать конверсий типов или указания generic аргументов в коде сайта:

```
var user = (MyUser)User.Load(id);
var user = User.Load<MyUser>(id);
```

Например, базово класс `User` имеет поля `id` и `name`. На сайте 1 нужно добавить поле `email`. А на сайте 2 нужно добавить поле `phone` (вместо `email`).

Если бы была одна библиотека (assembly), то это легко решалось бы с помощью partial class.

Есть у кого идеи, как решить данную задачу?

Comment: Хм. По-моему, generic — как раз подходящее решение. Почему бы не иметь один шаблонный параметр `U`? Тогда у вас было бы как-то так:

    class Library<U> where U : User
    {
        // ...
        var user = U.Load(id); // а уж U.Load возвращает именно U

Иначе у вас нарушится разделение ответственностей: библиотека будет _чересчур_ много знать о типах данных, с которой ей придётся работать (что не есть гуд).

Comment: Я подумал, что `U.Load` не прокатит: возвращаемый тип не пройдёт в generic constraint. Ну и ладно:

    Loader<U> uloader = ...
    var user = uloader.Load(id);

Comment: @VladD, я думал об этом, но как быть с возвращаемым типом других функций, находящихся в других классах. Например, у класса User есть поле Groups типа List<Group>, ну или любая другая функция, принимающая класс User в качестве аргумента.

Да и классов, которые нужно иметь возможность дополнять, будет больше.
Слишком много generic параметров получается.

Comment: @testr: Понимаю. Но, может быть, группу вам не нужно будет кастомизировать? И тогда у вас будет просто `Group<U>` всегда.

То есть особенной проблемы с многочисленными generic-параметрами я не вижу. Тем более, в приложениях вы всегда можете сказать

    using CustomLibrary = Library<CustomUser, CustomGroup, CustomEverythingYouWant>;

Answer (score 10):

Вы смотрите на partial классы под неверным углом зрения. Думаю лучшее объяснение того в чем здесь неточность - это описание причин, по которым частичные классы были созданы.

В первой версии C# частичных классов не было и это приводило к сложностям в работе с генерируемым кодом. Например, если вы сейчас используете Windows Forms, то код формы, который генерируется дизайнером, располагается в одном файле, а код, который пишете для формы вы - в другом. В C# 1 все лежало в одном файле и это вызывало серьезные проблемы. С одной стороны вы должны были вести себя осторожно, чтобы не сломать сгенерированный код, с другой стороны генератор кода должен был  обходить стороной ваш код. И эти проблемы возможны не только в gui-фреймворках, генерирующих код для создания графического интерфейса. Генерация кода используется, например, в ORM. Наконец, вы сами можете захотеть написать свой генератор.

Появление частичных классов в C# 2 решило эту проблему. Именно для этого были созданы частичные классы - *чтобы была возможность описать **один** класс в **нескольких** файлах*. Это позволило изолировать генерируемый код в отдельных файлах.

С тех пор были придуманы другие способы использования частичных классов, но и в этих способах причина применения частичных классов та же - необходимость разделить *один* класс на *несколько* файлов. Например:

- при написании unit-тестов обычно на каждый тестируемый класс создается один класс с тестами. Класс с тестами часто становится очень большим, намного большим чем тестируемый класс. В таких случаях класс с тестами можно сделать частичным и разделить на несколько файлов
- при рефакторинге кода часто встречается задача декомпозиции большого класса. Частичные классы в этом случае могут упростить работу. Можно сначала сделать класс частичным и безопасно разделить его на несколько файлов. И только когда все швы окончательно проясняться, выполнить реальное разделение на несколько классов.

Эти способы применения частичных классов отличаются от основного, но в них частичные классы служат той же цели: *они позволяют описать **один** класс в **нескольких** файлах*.

То что собираетесь сделать вы - совсем другое дело. Вы собираетесь описать *несколько* классов с помощью синтаксиса частичных классов. То есть вы хотите описать ***несколько*** классов так, как будто это **один** класс.

Более того, вы пытаетесь найти способ описать этот класс так, чтобы он лежал в нескольких сборках. Это равносильно кирпичу, который делят между собой стены соседних зданий.

Поэтому ответ на ваш вопрос такой - аналога partial class для разных assemblies не существует, вряд ли когда то будет существовать и не стоит пытаться его сымитировать.

Answer (score 3):

partial-классы между сборками существовать не могут. Зато можно сделать так, чтобы два проекта собирались в итоге в одну и ту же сборку.

Делается это так. Открываем проект с библиотекой, и дописываем ближе к концу что-то наподобие вот этого:

```
<Target Name="GetModuleCodeFiles" Outputs="@(Compile)" />
```

Теперь открываем файл с основным проектом, и дописываем вот такое:

```
<Target Name="ImportModule" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="путь к проекту библиотеки" Targets="GetModuleCodeFiles" RebaseOutputs="true">
        <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="Compile" />
    </MSBuild>
</Target>
```

Все, теперь при компиляции все файлы с исходным кодом из библиотеки окажутся как бы включенными в ваш основной проект.

Разумеется, это еще не все - ведь проект состоит не только из файлов с исходным кодом. Как минимум, придется таким же образом импортировать зависимости из библиотеки (References) - а также переписать логику загрузки пакетов из репозитория NuGet. Если в библиотеке есть ресурсы (EmbeddedResource) - понадобится импортировать еще и их. Но это все - решаемые проблемы.

Также может возникнуть проблема с R# - он не понимает динамического добавления файлов в проект. Для него понадобится включить проект с библиотекой как обычную зависимость - а потом не забыть убрать средствами MSBuild перед компиляцией:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Remove="путь к библиотеке" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Так что в целом то, что вы хотите, вполне достижимо. Но подумайте - не будет ли наследование с обобщенными типами проще?